# Displaying used formula in excel with Parameter names used in column A

Tags: excel, vba, xcode, defadvice

I need your expert advice to provide a VBA script that automatically displays used formula in excel.
For example

[image]

The cell D4 should display the formula used in B4 with the Parameter names used in column A.

The script below in VBA provides the formula with cell value! But I need with reference to Parameter name mentioned in column A.

```
Function GetFormula(Cell As Range) As String
   GetFormula = Cell.Formula
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your function stays in the same place, you could do something like this:

```
Public Function GetFormula(cell As Range) As String
    
    V_in = cell.Offset(-2, -1).Value 'Replace(cell.Address, "$", "")
    V_in_adr = cell.Offset(-2, -1).Address
    
    R_load = cell.Offset(-1, -1).Value   'Replace(cell.Address, "$", "")
    R_load_adr = cell.Offset(-1, -1).Address
    
    opr = Mid(cell.Formula, Len(V_in_adr), 1)

    GetFormula = "=" & V_in & opr & R_load

End Function
```

The function retrieves the operator used in the formula, and puts it in the middle of the value in each cell (V_in and R_load). Could be further imporved by using offset values as input to the formula, however this works for your current worksheet.